# How to insert data with IGNORE if one variable is allways different?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I would like to use INSERT IGNORE INTO in order to enter only data that doesnt exist allready in my database. Now my question is: How can I do this if I have a variable "time" which is allways different. But the rest would be the same.

For example:

```
"INSERT IGNORE INTO something (value1, value2, time)
VALUES ('".$value1."', '".$value2."', '".NOW()."')"
```

How could I tell INSERT IGNORE that he should insert all data even though the time (NOW()) is allways different?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

INSERT IGNORE would skip an insert only if a unique key is violated (not if all columns are the same). 
Define a unique key which includes all relevant columns, and does not include the time column.

Example: if you already have the record:

```
1,2,12:00
```

And a unique key which covers the first and second columns, running

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table VALUES(1,2,14:30)
```

Will not insert the record, while

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table VALUES(1,3,14:30)
```

Will insert a new record.

Comment: But I cant define a unique key with 50 relevant columns! How would you make sure, that only data is saved in the db which is not allready inside?

Comment: @phpheini you need to choose which columns should be unique (not all 50, which sounds unusual), or maybe create a checksum column which is unique?

Comment: I get an error message when I try to set a unique key: #1089 - Incorrect sub part key; the used key part isn't a string, the used length is longer than the key part, or the storage engine doesn't support unique sub keys

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a primary key to avoid the duplication of records

```
alter table something add primary key (value1,value2,time);
```