# MySQL INSERT IGNORE INTO keeps adding duplicate entries

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Here's the particular area im having an issue with

> ```
> mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO storeip (ip)
> VALUES ('$ip')");
> ```

when testing this it keeps adding the same entry to the table even though I have set IGNORE INTO.

Comment: If the IP is the only field on the table, just make it primary key and there will be no duplicates

Comment: Thanks that worked just fine, I didn't know you could do that :) 
Least I'm learning, however for future reference if this wasn't the only field on the table how would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: I'll edit this as an answer so you can accept it, If you have more field you just need to identify the fields that need to keep unique and make all Primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't have a `UNIQUE INDEX` on the IP column. In order for INSERT IGNORE to work as required, that's neccessary. Try this;

> ALTER TABLE ip ADD UNIQUE(ip)

To remove duplicates already, you can run this.

> ALTER IGNORE TABLE ip ADD UNIQUE(ip)

Comment: Thanks I set the row to the primary key to fix the problem , but yes I don't have a Unique Index, at least now I know how to fix this in the future if I have more than one field.

Comment: [similar question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914060/how-to-insert-data-with-ignore-if-one-variable-is-allways-different)

Comment: FYI, if your table is InnoDB, this can be a bad idea. InnoDB treats the primary key slightly differently than MyISAM. Typically best practice is to create an autoincrementing Primary Key, and then put a UNIQUE index on the data you need to be unique. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why shouldn't it? ignore just ignores errors. Make the ip unique.

```
alter table storip add unique (ip);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the IP is the only field on the table, just make it primary key and there will be no duplicates

```
alter table storeip add primary key (ip);
```